# Generating random index numbers from an array excluding some values

Tags: c++, vector, random, indexing

I need to extract 4 different random numbers from an array, excluding some index values. For example, in the code bellow I need to exclude 2 and 3.

Well, no problem, I create a lookup table containing only with the values I need, then 'random_number' +1, + 2, + 5... will give me the other 3 numbers. Won't work... because adding different numbers to a random number will give 2 or 3 at some point.

Why not generate 4 separate random numbers from the pool? There won't a 2 or 3, but especially from a small lookup table there will be duplicate random numbers...

I don't want to exclude those unwanted values from the array because this will mess with index calculations.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    static int rand_pool[]{0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    std::string years[] = {"2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010"};

    srand((int) time(0));
    int random_number = rand_pool[rand() % 8];
    std::vector <std::string> random_years = {years[random_number], years[1 + random_number],
                                              years[2+random number], years[3+random number]};
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator it;
    it = random_years.begin();
    for (it = random_years.begin(); it < random_years.end(); it++)
        std::cout << "\n" << *it << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Generate a vector of valid indices, `shuffle` those indices, then pick the first N indices from that.

Comment: You can go out of bounds of the `years` array. What happens if `random_number` happens to be `7`, `8` or `9` and you add `3`, `2` or `1` to it?

Comment: You have an array of valid indices, but how are the invalid indices (the ones you want to exclude) stored? Your code, and description, doesn't give any indication of that.

Comment: @cigien - invalid indices are not stored in a particular way, they are in every array - which has to be the exact same size, because there is a logical connection between index[8] of the array A and index [8] of the array B. So I can't delete invalid values from a particular array, I just need to ignore them.

Comment: No, I mean, how do you decide what the invalid indices are? In your question, you say 2 and 3 is an example. Where do those come from?

Comment: @cigien They are arbitrary picks, and for every given array must be introduced manually.

Comment: Generate a random number between 0 and the size of the array less the number of elements to skip. Index accordingly by missing out the forbidden indexes.

Comment: @NathanOliver how would you do it?  With 'std::generate' ?